# How to make a app for accessing iphone file system in windows OS

Tags: java, ios, .net, macos, filesystems

How to access iPhone file system using windows operating system. i'm trying to develop a app like [iexplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). But i could't get any api from apple side, I am looking for API's or methods to access an iPhone File system from Windows, can some one guide me how to do this stuff, is there any third party api for this?, if its so is that legal in apple policy?

I hope SO is right choice to ask this question.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please explain what this has to do with Java? Also .Net does not run (natively) on iOS.

Comment: @UwePlonus did you saw that link(iexplorer)?. i wanna create a desktop app like iexplorer using java or .net.